# Use react redux without server rendering

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, redux

So, I have been searching everywhere and can't find any hints on this.
 I have a REST API built with express that will be consumed by a website and in the future a mobile app.
I have to build the website and want to use react/redux, and I'm struggling to understand how to avoid the initial state to be render from server because I will have nested components and a lot of async data, and it will become a mess to maintain code both client- and server-side. Is there any solution/alternative for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Why would adding redux add more code to maintain server side?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need server-side rendering to solve this problem. You can make your components load with a blank state and then immediately fetch your data.

According to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), your ajax requests should be made in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, which fires once as soon as your initial render is complete.

> If you want to ... send AJAX requests, perform those
>   operations in this method.

For example, you don't load your app if a user isn't authenticated, or you put up loading spinners to indicate that data is being fetched.